# When is a good time to use readline()?

Tags: python, file

Many have asked how to read a file line by line in Python. And, instead of using readline(), many have recommended the following way:

```
with open('myfile.py') as f:
  for line in f:
```

Also, some said that readlines() is not an efficient way to use memory because it reads everything at once.

Is there any time that I should use readline() over the recommended method above? Or, should I forget about this function??

Comment: When you don't use `with`

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 What has that to do with `with`?

Comment: `readlines()` reads the whole file into a list. `readline()` only tries to read one line each time it's called. The first might be useful if you want to randomly access lines from in file using using list indices. Also, instead of `line = file.readline()`, you can use `line = next(file)` since file objects are iterable. This fact also make writing loops that process each line of a file easier to code because it's possible to write `for line in file:`, `...process line...` instead of `While True:`, `line = readline()`, `if not line: break`, `...process line...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `readline()` only if using `for` is not possible or useful.

Example: The file contains a fixed header like

- 1st line: Fixed identification string of file type
- 2nd line: filetype version identifier
- 3rd line: Size of following binary data
- Followed by: binary data of given amount

In such a case a `for`-loop would need some kind of line count variable to remember which line is currently processed.

This would end up in code like this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == 0:
        if line != "Foobar file format\n":
            raise Exception("Wrong file format")
    elif i == 1:
        if int(line) > 4:
            raise Exception("File format version too new")
    elif i == 2:
        size = int(line)
        break
```

instead of simply this

```
if f.readline() != "Foobar file format\n":
    raise Exception("Wrong file format")

if int(f.readline()) > 4:
    raise Exception("File format version too new")

size = int(f.readline())
```

(some error checks omitted for clarity)

Comment: Can you elaborate this? I am not getting why for loop is not effective in your example. Thanks!

Comment: @Heuyie I have updated the answer with a code sample.

Comment: Hi! It took a while to understand! Thank you so much for your update :)

Answer (score 1):

Readlines could be useful if you want to use each of the lines, one at a time, but not in the order that they appear inside of the file (ie, line 3->2->6->5->etc.).

Comment: You mean readlines not readline. Just wanted to make sure. :)